# Read multiple text file in single dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to read multiple text files into a single DataFrame in Pyspark and then apply the show() but getting the error in second file path.

`BUYERS10_m1 = spark.read.text(Buyers_F1_path,Buyers_F2_path)`

```
BUYERS10_m1.show()

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o245.showString.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: For input string: "s3a://testing/Buyers/File2.TXT"
```

Does anyone have any idea why I'm getting this error and how to resolve it ?

Comment: you can use wildcard `spark.read.text("s3a://testing/Buyers/*.txt")`

Comment: wildcard works but I need to read specific files from the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should work.

```py
spark.read.text("s3a://testing/Buyers/File{1,2}.TXT")
```